# Changing a file line - Python

Tags: python, file

I've a file entitled **'users.txt'** with the following structure; `username:info_about_the_user.`

Something like this:

**users.txt:**

> mark:stuffabouthim
>  anthony:stuffabouthim
>  peter:stuffabouthim
>  peterpeter:stuffabouthim
>  peterpeterpeter:stuffabouthim
>  peterpeterpeterpeter:stuffabouthim

The following part of the script needs to change a line (change info about an user) but I'm having problems when the string is duplicated (peter - peterpeter) and I dont know how to fix it.

```
def test():
    fn = 'users.txt'
    f = open(fn)
    output = []
    changeuser = 'peterpeter'
    userinfo = 'HeIsTall'
    for line in f:
        if not changeuser+":" in line:
            output.append(line)
    f.close()
    f = open(fn, 'w')
    f.writelines(output)
    f.close()
    f = open("users.txt", "a")
    f.write(changeuser + ":" + userinfo+"\n")
    f = open("users.txt", "a")

test()
```

This is the input I have:

**Input: users.txt:**

> mark:stuffabouthim
>  anthony:stuffabouthim
>  peter:stuffabouthim
>  **peterpeter:HesAwesome**
>  peterpeterpeter:stuffabouthim
>  peterpeterpeterpeter:stuffabouthim

I want to change info about peterpeter and have the following output:

**Output I want to have: users.txt:**

> mark:stuffabouthim
>  anthony:stuff about him
>  peter:stuffabouthim
>  **peterpeter:HeIsTall**
>  peterpeterpeter:stuffabouthim
>  peterpeterpeterpeter:stuffabouthim

But this is the input I'm having. All the lines behind peterpeter are getting deleted among other things.

> mark:stuffabouthim
>       anthony:stuffabouthim
>       peter:stuffabouthim
>       peterpeter:HeIsTall

Can anyone give me a help with the code below to have the desired output? Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need python for this? You might be better off with awk + sed linux commands.

Comment: and if he would want to do it in assembler he would have a reason to do so - btw. it almost certainly looks like homework to me! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
def test():
    fn = 'users.txt.txt'
    f = open(fn)
    output = []
    changeuser = 'peterpeter'
    userinfo = 'HeIsTall'
    for line in f:
        if line.strip().split(':')[0]!=changeuser:
            output.append(line)
        else:
            output.append(changeuser + ":" + userinfo+"\n")

    f.close()
    f = open(fn, 'w')
    f.writelines(output)
    f.close()

test()
```

**output:**

```
mark:stuffabouthim
anthony:stuffabouthim
peter:stuffabouthim
peterpeter:HeIsTall
peterpeterpeter:stuffabouthim
peterpeterpeterpeter:stuffabouthim
```

Comment: It's mostly ok, but that appends it on the last line. like this: 
peterpeterpeterpeter:stuffabouthimpeterpeter:HeIsTall

Do you know how to put them in different lines?

Answer (score 3):

You can have it the easy way with the [`fileinput`](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) module:

```
import fileinput

def test():
    fn = 'users.txt'

    changeuser = 'peterpeter'
    newinfo = 'HeIsTall'

    for line in fileinput.input(fn, inplace=1):
        user, oldinfo = line.split(':')
        print '%s:%s' % (user, newinfo if user == changeuser else oldinfo.replace('\n', ''))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Answer (score 2):

You got a logical error in the `if`-clause, which **DELETES** all peters*, the only peter remaining is the one you append to the file.

```
for line in f:
        if not changeuser+":" in line:  #THAT MEANS ALL PETERS ARE IGNORED!
            output.append(line)
```

It's generaly easier to understand positive clauses then a negation:

```
for line in f:
   if changeuser+":" in line:
      output.append('%s:%s\n' %(changeuser,userinfo))
   else:
      output.append(line)
```

Good code is easy to read. Try to code like you would try to write a report! That leads automatically to spliting your code into smaller pieces like functions. e.g.:

```
lines = read_all_lines_from_file(filename)
change_user_info(lines, user, userinfo)
save_lines_to_file(lines, filename)
```

Your code gets split into smaller pieces and if an error occurs you can pin it down to a few lines of code instead of having to work over several pages. ;-)